# MVC Repository pattern correct business logic location

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am using MVC4,EF5, repository pattern and Unity IoC.
Where should the logic code block be placed?

- inside the repository of the specific model
- the controller
- or by extending the partial class of the model? as a static function?

In my application each controller holds an instance of the unit of work. In case the logic will be held inside one of the repositories or inside a partial class, thus requiring to send the unit of work as a parameter. What would you recommend as best practice?

thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'logic'? Business logic? Repositories should be injected with the appropriate Unit of Work.

Comment: I have a complicated business logic which I want to code in my app.
it seems to me that the controller is not the right place for it, since i don't want it to be full of logic. neither inside the repository itself.
in the other hand, if i use a partial class (using a static function) i would have to send a reference of the Unit Of Work..

Comment: I would put it in a Command Handler. Our controllers pass all logic to CommandHandlers and they and business entities contain all business logic. Basically following something similar to this article http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91. Our controllers don't know anything about repositories or unit of work as these are all injected in Command Handler

Answer (score 0):

As GraemeMiller highlights, controllers should be absent of business logic. I think that a repository should be fairly light in terms of business logic, too. Dino Esposito recommends a similar pattern to GraemeMiller, in that the controller hands-off the viewmodel to some kind of co-ordinator that uses various other classes to do its job, generating a modified viewmodel or re-directing to another controller as appropriate. Your co-ordinator could be dependent on a unit of work or it might establish one itself. I'd favour the former.